# Concatenating values into new layer of raster stack

Tags: r, concatenation, raster

I wish to combine the values of two rasters, however by that I mean concatenate instead of sum. For example, instead of 1 + 1 = 2, I want 1 + 1 = 11. Further I want both numbers retained, so 0 + 1 = 01, not 1. I am able to accomplish this by converting the rasters into dataframes, but I can't convert them back to rasters (I'm hoping to make a map as the final product). Further, I can't figure out how to accomplish this while keeping the data a raster class.

Here is some sample code to illustrate my problem:

```
library(raster)
#Create two rasters
xmn = 1; xmx = 5; ymn = 10; ymx = 20 
rast1<- raster(matrix(1,3,4), xmx=xmx, xmn=xmn, ymx=ymx, ymn=ymn)
rast2<- raster(matrix(2,3,4), xmx=xmx, xmn=xmn, ymx=ymx, ymn=ymn)
```

All the cells in rast 1 and rast2 are 1 and 2, respectively. Concatenating these two rasters should result in values of 12. However, the only way I know how to do this is converting the rasters into a dataframe, like so:

```
#Stack the rasters and convert to data frame
rast_df<- as.data.frame(stack(rast1, rast2))

#Concatenate using the layer stack (layer.1 for rast1, layer.2 for rast2)
rast_con<- transform(rast_df, layer.3=paste(layer.1, layer.2, sep = ""))

#Inspect layer.3 values
head(rast_con)
  layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
1       1       2      12
2       1       2      12
3       1       2      12
4       1       2      12
5       1       2      12
```

As we can see, this approach works. However I can't seem to coerce the dataframe back to the raster with the original extent/CRS with just layer.3. Any tips on how to do this, or how to concatenate the two rasters without converting them to a dataframe, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two rasters with fewer than 10 unique values, you can multiply one with 10, like this

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(matrix(1:2, 3,4), xmx=5, xmn=1, ymx=5, ymn=1)
r2 <- raster(r1)
r2[] <- c(1,1,2,2)

x <- 10 * r1 + r2
plot(x)
text(x)
```

Another approach

```
s <- stack(r1, r2)
combinations <- c("11", "12", "21", "22")
f <- function(x) {
    x <- paste0(x[,1], x[,2])
    match(x, combinations)
}

r <- calc(s, f)
plot(r)
text(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I may have found a potential solution, though I don't know WHY this is a solution. So if anyone can provide a simpler answer, or explain why this answer works, I would appreciate it.

When you have rast_con created, you can do this:

```
#Create a matrix out of the layer with the concatenated values, but you have to make it 
#A character, then a numeric, before coercing to matrix. I don't know why
rast_mat<- as.matrix(as.numeric(as.character(rast_con$layer.3)))

#Inspecting the matrix, we see this works
head(rast_mat)
     [,1]
[1,]   12
[2,]   12
[3,]   12
[4,]   12
[5,]   12
[6,]   12

#Create a raster from the matrix, using the same extent parameters as before
rast_final<- raster(rast_elf, xmx=xmx, xmn=xmn, ymx=ymx, ymn=ymn)

#Inspect rast_final to ensure it works
head(rast_final)
  1
1  12
2  12
3  12
4  12
5  12
6  12
7  12
8  12
9  12
10 12
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not much support for raster of string in R yet, which string is probably needed for achieving your goal. The easiest solution I can think of is to create a factor-valued raster and stick to factor raster as described [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/factor.html).

```
s0 = brick(rast1, rast2)
coords = coordinates(s0) 

s1 = as.data.frame(getValues(s0))
s1$layer.1 = 0
layer.3 = sapply(1:nrow(s1), function(x) paste0(s1[x, ], collapse = ''))
layer.3 <- data.frame(coords, layer.3)
layer.3$layer.3 <- factor(layer.3$layer.3, levels = unique(layer.3$layer.3))
coordinates(layer.3) <- ~ x + y
gridded(layer.3) <- TRUE
layer.3 <- raster(layer.3)

layer.3
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 3, 4, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 1, 3.333333  (x, y)
# extent     : 1, 5, 10, 20  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : NA 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer.3 
# values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
# attributes :
#   ID levels
# 1     02

levels(layer.3)

# [[1]]
# ID levels
# 1  1     02
```

Comment: This works. Just one point for people reading this, you'll want to make a new variable, such as r<- calc(s, fun = function(x) as.numeric(paste0(x, collapse = ''))), for it to work.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work because if rast1 has values of 0, and rast2 has values of 2, the output of this code will be 2 instead of 02. Same with my solution below...

Comment: It does, but now it's no longer in raster format. Thank you!

Comment: It appears to me that you need to operate on strings to achieve what you want, in which case you will need to convert them to factors. I updated my answer accordingly. check if that works for you.